# Is it possible to recompile Vaadin widgetset at runtime?

Tags: java, vaadin

I was wondering if this is even possible and if so then how. Could you be so kind and post some solutions?
Let's say we have 2 discreet addresses. One Is used for vaadin and other by normal http servlet to start recompilation process or second http servlet is running on different port number.

So what would need to be done is:
1. Clear old widgetset
2. Issue compilation of new widgetset

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: My best guess is to launch ant task from server you are running. You can compile widgetset from ant. Take a look here: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/clientside.compiling.html

Comment: I'm using maven for it but this shouldn't matter. I wanted to be able to recompile widgetset from Glassfish's JMX Console. So it would be best if maven could be invoked programatically instead of invoking shell command.

Comment: check, how it is done in maven/ant/gradle/... it's basically a call to the compiler to make it going.  but it needs all the source(jars) and might e.g. clash (e.g. java-validation 1.1 vs 1.0).  so start it as a new process to be on the safe side?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the use case here is. What are the reasons why you need a new widget set during runtime? Users can drop in add-ons and somehow dynamically/magically the software knows how to use them? Do you have to package a new war also at the same? I have a feeling that what you want to achieve is achievable in some other manner as well. Anyhow, the compiler is in the vaadin-client-compiler and is not added to runtime. It actually causes conflicts if you add it to runtime and the application won't develop. There might be ways around it but it all sounds a bit iffy.

Comment: It's simple. I want to make webdesktop app in which users could add new apps at runtime. I'm just looking for a way to do this. I know I could use just javascript but I don't like javascript as such and I have much more experience in developing software in vaadin. Normally this functionality wouldn't be needed as all client side components would be already compiled in but I just want to have an option to recompile everything when needed by new uncommon client side control to be added to the project.

Comment: Let's say that I was able to build my project without the functionality of widgetset recompilation. I sell my product to some company with one of my apps in it. Later I will develop some other app which this company would like. But the app would utilize new component which wasn't available when they bought the app. So they would need to update their installation to new version of the webdeskop-app-core just because there are new client-side-controls. This could lead to problems if there are more teams working on apps for webdesktop. I was planning to use OSGi for modularity support.

Comment: But later I also found out about liferay and whole concept of portlets. If normal way of integrating new apps to the project would fail then I'll try to do it with portlets where whole apps will have their own app on webserver.

Comment: I just own Synology NAS server with DSM OS on it and would like to get the same in java/scala using vaadin. That's all.